# Simple int / simple string expectet

Tags: pine-script

I want to save multiple settings in one indicator. But I always get the following error messages:
09:21:13    Fehler in 108:25 Cannot call 'ta.ema' with argument 'length'='ema_len1'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.
09:21:13    Fehler in 109:43 Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'timeframe'='res'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected.

```
        type Strategy_settings
            string res = "60"
            int ema_len1 = 0
            float ema_mult_1 = 0
            int ema_len2 = 0
            int ema_len3 = 0
            float ema_mult_3 = 0


        // TYPES AND METHODS

        // STRATS
        selector(string strategy_name) =>
            strategy_settings = Strategy_settings.new()
            switch strategy_name
                "EIGENE EINSTELLUNG" =>
                    strategy_settings.res := "60"
                    strategy_settings.ema_len1 := 50
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_1 := 0.05
                    strategy_settings.ema_len2 := 75
                    strategy_settings.ema_len3 := 100
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_3 := 0.3

                "UNIVERSAL M15" => 
                    strategy_settings.res := "60"
                    strategy_settings.ema_len1 := 50
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_1 := 0.05
                    strategy_settings.ema_len2 := 75
                    strategy_settings.ema_len3 := 100
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_3 := 0.3
                "LINK M60" => 
                    strategy_settings.res := "120"
                    strategy_settings.ema_len1 := 34
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_1 := 0.1
                    strategy_settings.ema_len2 := 110
                    strategy_settings.ema_len3 := 195
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_3 := 1.28
                "DOT M30" => 
                    strategy_settings.res := "15"
                    strategy_settings.ema_len1 := 49
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_1 := 0.11
                    strategy_settings.ema_len2 := 87
                    strategy_settings.ema_len3 := 106
                    strategy_settings.ema_mult_3 := 0.23
            strategy_settings
        // STRATS


        //@version=5
        indicator(title='EMAeinstellungen div Coins', shorttitle='EMAeinstellungen div Coins', overlay=true)

        bool emaTrend_setzen = false
        string res = "60"
        int ema_len1 = 50
        float ema_mult_1 = 0.00
        int ema_len2 = 90
        int ema_len3 = 150
        float ema_mult_3 = 0.30

        // INPUTS
        // Strategieauswahl 
        strategy_input = input.string(title = "STRATEGY", options = [
            "EIGENE EINSTELLUNG",
            ">>bisher nur manuell!!!<<",
            "UNIVERSAL M15",
            "LINK M60",
            "DOT M30",
            "===============",
            "xxxxx1",
            "xxxxx2",
            "xxxxx3",
            "xxxxx4"
            ], defval = "EIGENE EINSTELLUNG", tooltip = "EN:\nTo manually configure the strategy, select EIGENE EINSTELLUNG otherwise, changing the settings won't have any effect\n \nkeine fertigen strategien!!!!!!!!!")



        // EMA-Cross anderer Timeframe
        var emaTrend = " EMA Trend"

        res_input = input.timeframe(title="/Timeframe", defval="60", group=emaTrend, inline = "htf ema 1")

        // EMA1
        ema_len1_input = input.int(title="EMA1 Kurzperiode", defval=53, group=emaTrend, tooltip='EMA-Cross gilt für EMA1 mit EMA3 / EMA-Folge gleich EMA1<>EMA2<>EMA3 / Close muss über EMA2 sein')
        ema_mult_1_input = input.float(0.050, minval=0.000, step=0.001, title='EMA1 Standardabweichungen', group=emaTrend)

        // EMA2
        ema_len2_input = input.int(title="EMA2 Mittelperiode", defval=90, group=emaTrend)

        // EMA3
        ema_len3_input = input.int(title="EMA3 Langperiode", defval=175, group=emaTrend)
        ema_mult_3_input = input.float(0.30, minval=0.000, step=0.001, title='EMA3 Standardabweichungen', group=emaTrend)


        var Strategy_settings strategy_s = na

        strategy_s := strategy_input == "EIGENE EINSTELLUNG" ? Strategy_settings.new(res_input, ema_len1_input, ema_mult_1_input, ema_len2_input, ema_len3_input, ema_mult_3_input) : selector(strategy_input)


        res := strategy_s.res
        ema_len1 := strategy_s.ema_len1
        ema_mult_1 := strategy_s.ema_mult_1
        ema_len2 := strategy_s.ema_len2
        ema_len3 := strategy_s.ema_len3
        ema_mult_3 := strategy_s.ema_mult_3



        htf_ma1 = ta.ema(close, ema_len1)
        out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, htf_ma1)
        ema_dev_1 = ta.stdev(close, ema_len1)
        ema_upper_1 = out1 + ema_mult_1 * ema_dev_1
        ema_lower_1 = out1 - ema_mult_1 * ema_dev_1


        plot(out1, color=color.purple, title='EMA1', linewidth=1)
        plot(ema_upper_1, color=color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 100), title='EMA1 Obere Standardabweichung')
        plot(ema_lower_1, color=color.purple, title='EMA1 Untere Standardabweichung')



        htf_ma2 = ta.ema(close, ema_len2)
        out2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, htf_ma2)
        ema_dev_2 = ta.stdev(close, ema_len2)

        plot(out2, color=color.rgb(255, 153, 0, 50), title='EMA2', linewidth=1)



        htf_ma3 = ta.ema(close, ema_len3)
        out3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, htf_ma3)
        ema_dev_3 = ta.stdev(close, ema_len2)
        ema_upper_3 = out3 + ema_mult_3 * ema_dev_3
        ema_lower_3 = out3 - ema_mult_3 * ema_dev_3

        plot(out3, color=color.fuchsia, title='EMA2', linewidth=1)
        plot(ema_upper_3, color=color.rgb(223, 64, 251, 100), title='EMA2 Obere Standardabweichung')
        plot(ema_lower_3, color=color.fuchsia, title='EMA2 Untere Standardabweichung')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable length in `ema`. As the error message tells you, it expects a length of type [`simple`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#simple). That means, its value must remain the same during the execution of the script.

> Values qualified as “simple” are available only once the script begins
> execution on the first chart bar of its history, and they remain
> consistent during the script’s execution.

Comment: The value should only be unique. Depending on the selection of the coin, it can be accessed.
Unfortunately, I don't understand what I have to change in order to be able to save these as defaults.